# How to redirect url from https://example.com/12345.html to https://example.com/product/12345/ using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My most social media links are like https://example.com/12345.html and I want to redirect them to https://example.com/product/12345/

Here 12345 is the dynamic page that changes as per different products.

How can it be done using the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also I believe you are looking for rewrite not redirect(which changes URL in browser itself).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^product/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```